# Why does my LIKE filter only match on one value?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-query

I have [this excel file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=81265269456405561782) which is giving me unexpected results on an SQL query with a join on `LIKE` criteria.

Here is the SQL statement:

```
SELECT CO.MATERIALS, CO.SIZES, CO.TOOLS, IR.PN, IR.BODYJAW

FROM  `CROSSJOIN$` CO
LEFT JOIN `INSERTS$` IR 

    ON CO.TOOLS=IR.TOOL
    AND ((IR.MATERIAL Like '%'+CO.MATERIALS+'%'))
    AND ((IR.SIZE Like '%'+CO.SIZES+'%'))
```

And the issue is, that the criteria for `IR.MATERIAL` will *only* match on one value "333".  I can't figure it out.  Here's a visual explanation of the what's happening (in case you don't want to download file):

[image]

The other two filters work just fine, separately or in combination, and all matches come back as expected.  It's just this `MATERIAL` field that is giving me heartburn.  If I delete the other two filters out of the SQL statement, I still only get matches on records with material "333" and if I delete that material from the left table, I get no matches at all.

Does anyone know what would cause this behavior?
As a sanity check, I tried vlookup in excel on these tables and it matched material without problem, so the data is right and does match.

Comment: Cory - you're a genius.  If you want to make your comment an answer, I will mark it as correct.  I changed all columns to be formatted as text and I'm getting the results I needed.  Thanks!!

Comment: I'd be curious if my edit works as well: adding `IMEX=1` to your Excel connection string. Original comment converted to an answer.

Comment: I tried to change formatting back to "general" so that I could test the "IMEX" setting, but it seems once I set it to "TEXT" once it was a permanent fix, because I couldn't get it to revert back to prior behavior no matter what format I set to (even number).  But - interestingly - after adding IMEX=1 to the conn string, and hitting "okay", the next time I went to edit the connection string it wasn't there.  Tried it a couple times to be sure, but excel (or MS Query) seems to remove that for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting that only the `333` matches.

I think what's happening is that the first values Excel is seeing in your Material columns is 333, so it's inferring the column type is an `Integer` value, which would limit the potential matches to other Integer values.

You could test that theory by fudging other material codes -- make a "444" or something in each worksheet and see if that matches. If that's the case, **ensure that the datatypes of the columns are what you want them to be (all text, I assume)**.

Alternatively, adding `IMEX=1` to your connection string might be easier -- it will make the Excel data reader treat all data as strings.

Comment: Note - excel (or MS Query) seems to remove `IMEX=1` for some reason. I tried adding it to the connection string (just at the end of the string) and after committing it, the next time I went to edit the connection string it wasn't there. Tried it a couple times to be sure, but it just disappears - no warning or notification to the user in any way, it's just gone.  Not sure why, but wanted to note it for others who find this answer later on.